# Difference in use of ** and pow function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-regression

while attempting to write a cost function for linear regression the error is arising while replacing ** with pow function in cost_function :

Original cost function

```
def cost_function(x,y,theta):
    m = np.size(y)
    j = (1/(2*m))*np.sum(np.power(np.matmul(x,theta)-y),2)
    return j
```

Cost function giving the error:

```
def cost_function(x,y,theta):
        m = np.size(y)
        j = (1/(2*m))*np.sum((np.matmul(x,theta)-y)**2)
        return j
```

Gradient Descent

```
def gradient_descent(x,y,theta,learn_rate,iters):
    x = np.mat(x);y = np.mat(y); theta= np.mat(theta);
    m = np.size(y)
    j_hist = np.zeros(iters)
    for i in range(0,iters):
        temp = theta - (learn_rate/m)*(x.T*(x*theta-y))
        theta = temp
        j_hist[i] = cost_function(x,y,theta)
    return (theta),j_hist
```

Variable values

```
theta  = np.zeros((2,1))
learn_rate = 0.01
iters = 1000
x is (97,2) matrix
y is (97,1) matrix
```

cost function is calculated fine with value of 32.0727
The error arises while using the same function in gradient descent.

The error am getting is **LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square**

Comment: This may be related to the data, would you please add a small amount of the data to your question for purpose of illustration?

Comment: `pow(x,y)` should be equivalent to `x**y`, as stated from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). Can you post your incorrect code?

Comment: @Mstaino I have edited the question please review it again for any fault

Comment: @Mstaino, he doesn't use `pow`, despite the subject line.  What worked was `np.power`, which for `np.matrix` objects is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's distinguish between `pow`, `**` and `np.power`.  `pow` is the Python function, that according to docs is equivalent to `**` when used with 2 arguments.

Second, you apply `np.mat` to the arrays, making `np.matrix` objects.  According to its docs:

> It has certain special operators, such as `*`
>   (matrix multiplication) and `**` (matrix power).

matrix power:

```
In [475]: np.mat([[1,2],[3,4]])**2
Out[475]: 
matrix([[ 7, 10],
        [15, 22]])
```

Elementwise square:

```
In [476]: np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])**2
Out[476]: 
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 9, 16]])
In [477]: np.power(np.mat([[1,2],[3,4]]),2)
Out[477]: 
matrix([[ 1,  4],
        [ 9, 16]])
```

Matrix power:

```
In [478]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [479]: arr@arr            # np.matmul
Out[479]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

With a non-square matrix:

```
In [480]: np.power(np.mat([[1,2]]),2)
Out[480]: matrix([[1, 4]])             # elementwise
```

Attempting to do `matrix_power` on a non-square matrix:

```
In [481]: np.mat([[1,2]])**2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-481-18e19d5a9d6c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.mat([[1,2]])**2

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __pow__(self, other)
    226 
    227     def __pow__(self, other):
--> 228         return matrix_power(self, other)
    229 
    230     def __ipow__(self, other):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in matrix_power(a, n)
    600     a = asanyarray(a)
    601     _assertRankAtLeast2(a)
--> 602     _assertNdSquareness(a)
    603 
    604     try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _assertNdSquareness(*arrays)
    213         m, n = a.shape[-2:]
    214         if m != n:
--> 215             raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
    216 
    217 def _assertFinite(*arrays):

LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Note that the whole traceback lists `matrix_power`.  That's why we often ask to see the whole traceback.

Why are you setting `x`,`y` and `theta` to `np.mat`?  The `cost_function` uses `matmul`.  With that function, and its `@` operator, there are few(er) good reasons for using `np.matrix`.

Despite the subject line, you did not try to use `pow`.  That confused me and at least one other commentator.  I tried to find a `np.pow` or a `scipy` version.